# Help me correct these properties of : $f_{n}(x)= nx(1-x)^{n}$? Is there maybe a typo in the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Examine the sequence  of functions $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ on $x\in[0,1]$:

$$f_{n}(x)= nx(1-x)^{n}$$

1. Does $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge pointwise or uniform?

I will show that it does converge pointwise to 0 by taking the limit and applying l'hôpitals rule: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nx(1-x)^n = 0 $$ because for $x=0,1$  it follows directly that $f_n=0$ and for  $0<x<1$: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-x)^n \rightarrow 0$ from some n faster than $nx \rightarrow \infty$

If $(f_n)$ were uniform convergent, then : $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup(|f_n-0|) = 0 $ but if we insert $x= \frac{1}{n}$ we see that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup (|(1-\frac{1}{n})^n-0)|=\frac{1}{e}$ so $(f_n)$ can not be uniform convergent.

*2 Why is it that: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (f_n) =\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(f_n) $ ?

Is it because both limits make the sequence go to 0 independently?

*3. Is the limit function of $(f_n)$ continuous?

This question makes me think that maybe there was a typo made when writing the function sequence, because who would ask to show continuity for $f(t)=0$ ?

*4 $(f_n)_n$ is allowed to be integrate partwise 
How can I show this fact ?

Can you see what the typo could have possibly been? If there was no typo made, are my answers correct? What can I do better?

Comment: I suspect they just wanted you to note that it is possible for a sequence of continuous functions to converge nonuniformly to a continuous function.

Comment: In 4., are they asking if $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx\rightarrow \int_0^1 0\,dx$? If so,   a direct calculation will give you the answer (substitute $u=1-x$ for the integral on the left).

Comment: I assume that partwise integration of a function sequence is the same as showing that the sequence of integrals converges.

Comment: Did I solve the rest of the questions correctly?

Comment: They look ok; although your reasoning in computing the limit in 1. is a bit unclear. It might be best to explicitly evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {x(1-x)^n\over 1/n}$ (by L'Hopital, e.g.). Also, in 2., you could explicitly evaluate the limits (I'm not quite sure how they expect you to answer   this).